# Geometry Node Object floating above and below

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a landscape with scattered rocks using geometry nodes.  These seem to float above and below and I am not finding the secret sauce to get these rocks embedded in the ground and not rotated on the Z and looking vertical.  The random x, y values are 0-360 for x and y rotation.

Basically I want random rocks, random scale, weight map placed rocks that are sunk into the ground a bit and never standing upright, vertically.

[image]

Comment: If your question was solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted Answer". This will make it easier for others to see which way leads to the solution, and the question will no longer appear as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still didn't get a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply enable the *Reset Children* option in the `Collection Info` node.

If the option *Reset Children* is not activated, their position relative to their own center will be processed.

[image]

However, the individual zero point of the individual objects is always decisive here. In your case, this should be in the center of each object.

You can change this point either by moving your mesh in *Edit Mode* or by changing it with *Set Origin*.

Answer (score 0):

Click on *reset children* in *collection info* node.

If you want them to keep scale, apply scale for each rock object (<kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> → Scale)

Comment: That helped but there remains similar issue, although that definitely decreased the deviations.  Rocks are still above and below the surface and rotated to vertical.  All transforms are already applied

Comment: Check where the origin is. Origin  is a small dot, that's highlighted then you select the object. If it is outside the rock - click *Set Origin* ⇾ *Geometry to Origin*  in the context menu

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to @Crantisz's answer, add a *Rotate Euler* node, take the rotation output of the distribute on points node, plug it into the rotation input of the rotate Euler node, set it to local, plug the combine XYZ node into the rotation value of the rotate euler node, and connect the output of the rotate euler node to the rotation of the instances on points node.